# Can I use GPS for Indoor Navigation?

Tags: navigation, gps, xamarin.android

Is it possible to use GPS localisation for indoor navigation even for small accurancy and in a wide building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can, but it's going to be really off. Due to the reflection from walls, GPS nearly always shows you outside of the building, regardless where you are inside. The exception are wooden houses with thin walls, where GPS works surprisingly well. Another exception are venues mapped by Google or Apple, where native location functions well (limited to some big airports, stadiums etc).

The question is, what you are trying to achieve and how good accuracy you need. I would recommend using some BLE beacons or for example IndoorAtlas that is based on Earth's geomagnetic fields.

(Disclosure: I work for Proximi.io that is a unified positioning platform, supports IndoorAtlas, GPS etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I am developping also the indoor localisation based on gemagnetic fields of earth. But I wanted to know if I can enhance the application with GPS.